# Push_back function for Class defined vector

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I have a vector that takes in class values of a class called Bug which stores a mass and number of legs for each instance. I'm having trouble using the push_back function, and suspect it's just a syntax issue, but can't figure out exactly what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to add 3 more values into the end of the vector. Here is my partial code:

```
std::vector<Bug> bugs(5); //vector definition
bugs.push_back(3);
```

Comment: @user1438832 what would the syntax be for this? Just replace push_back with emplace_back?

Comment: `push_back()` adds only one element. If you want to add 3 more elements, either call `push_back()` 3 times or call `resize()` with the appropriate new size you want.

Comment: @Cornstalks Thats exactly what I was looking for, I was unaware of the resize function. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are trying to add 3 default constructed Bugs, you will need to call `push_back` 3 times:

```
struct Bug{};  
std::vector<Bug> bugs(5); //vector instantiation 
bugs.push_back(Bug{});
bugs.push_back(Bug{});
bugs.push_back(Bug{});
```

You can also use `emplace_back`([c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)).  It expects constructor arguments.
In this case, no arguments:

```
struct Bug{};  
std::vector<Bug> bugs(5);
bugs.emplace_back();
bugs.emplace_back();
bugs.emplace_back();
```

Apart from using a loop, you can add N new elements using `resize`:

```
bugs.resize(bugs.size()+n);
```